# Eclipse/ apache-tomcat-7.0.34 server unable to define a New Server

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat7

The 404 error message when trying to run Servlet on eclipse/tomcat incited me to follow a step by step Tutorial on: http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html

Tutorial is great but arrived at a certain step of the tutorial(server setup), i'm asked to define a new server in the Eclipse wizard (right click on server tab => new server etc..), whish i've already done hundreds of times today with tomcat 7(so i know how it works).

The problem here is that i'm using a predefined tomcat version that has been customed an provided (without an installer)by the tutor. 
I unzipped it succesfully etc... but when i hit the "Tomcat v7.0 Server" option in the list of servers of the wizard, it looks empty and of course the "Next>" button is greyed-out.

Is there a way to import the server in the wizard?

It used to work when i downloaded the version : 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

OOps Solved. 
It was just : Windows => Preferences => server => Add (button)